# How to avoid BufferUnderflowException

Tags: java, exception, buffer

I'm using this function to convert bytearray to int.

```
public static int byteArrayToInt(byte[] b) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(b);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    return bb.getInt();
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting  java.nio.BufferUnderflowException at the return statement. I'm calling this function many times by the way. I read that it happens when more bytes are being read than the buffer size. But can anyone tell me how to avoid it?

Is there a way to copy my original bytearray to new bytearray of size 4 and pass this bytearray to the function?

UPDATE:
I tried this in  main method:

```
byte[] bbTemp=new byte[4];
bbTemp = originalbyteArray;
```

And passed bbTemp to the above function, but it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

A `BufferUnderflowException` [will be thrown](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)

> If there are fewer than four bytes remaining in this buffer

Make sure your `byte[]` has at least 4 bytes in it, which is the size of an `int`.

Comment: Exactly. I need to compress stuff, and I don't want my Bytebuffer to be 4 bytes unnecessarily. I don't mind having a temp Bytebuffer  inside the function. But later, I want to calculate the exact size in bytes that my Bytebuffer takes in the main method.

Comment: @user An `int` is represented in memory with 4 bytes. There is no way around this. You should post what you are trying to achieve and you might get better help.

Comment: I mean if the function returns int with 4 bytes, that is fine. I just don't want to change the original Bytebuffer in my main method to 4 bytes. Can that be done?

Comment: @user2441441 The method returns and `int`. But it cannot construct that `int` unless you pass it an array with 4 bytes.

Comment: @user Consider first what your original byte array is storing. What is the meaning of those bytes? Does it make sense to try and convert them to an `int`? I don't see the purpose right now.